# Can jsonschema's format keyword take multiple values?

Tags: python, jsonschema

I am using jsonschema to validate JSON blobs in which a particular property can either be a date or a datetime. As such I would like the `format` keyword to allow multiple potential formats.

For example, the following code works:

```
import rfc3339_validator

schema = {
    "title": "example",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["example_property"],
    "properties": {
        "example_property": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
        }
    }
}

validate(instance, schema, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
```

But ideally I would use `format` with a list of potential formats, e.g. `["date-time", "date"]`.

Is there a way of achieving this? My temporary workaround is to use the `pattern` keyword to ensure that the property at least contains a date.

Comment: `format` only takes a single value. The solution below is a good one.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the [`anyOf`](https://docs.opis.io/json-schema/1.x/multiple-subschemas.html#anyof) keyword like so:

```py
import jsonschema
import rfc3339_validator

schema = {
    "title": "example",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["example_property"],
    "properties": {
        "example_property": {
            "type": "string",
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                {
                    "format": "date"
                }
            ]

        }
    }
}

date_instance = {"example_property": "1970-01-01"}
date_time_instance = {"example_property": "2019-10-12T07:20:50.52Z"}
nonsense_instance = {"example_property": "nonsense"}

jsonschema.validate(date_instance, schema, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
jsonschema.validate(date_time_instance, schema, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
jsonschema.validate(nonsense_instance, schema, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
```